# Adding .Net MVC 5 script bundles on a per request basis

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, css, iis-7

Were building a widget based website that should be able to live as widgets on external sites as well. Were going to be using bundles to handle our view dependencys, as follows:

In bundleconfig.cs:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/widgetspecific"));
```

On the widget with the dependecys:

```
@{

var bundle = System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.GetRegisteredBundles()
    .Where(b => b.Path == "~/widgetspecific")
    .First();

bundle.Include("~/Scripts/andreas.js");

 }
```

On the layout page, or in the component that should be able to live on another site:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/widgetspecific")
```

It has now come to our attention that since the widgetspecific bundle is added through the Global.asax Application_Start() function all the users on our site is going to be adding the same bundle rendering on all of the pages, since the bundle is added on the Application_Start. Is there some way to make the bundles specific to the current request?